# Azure Resources Deployment using ARM template removes the existing Application config

Tags: azure-rm-template

I have created a Function App for Containers using ARM template deployment using Azure DevOps Pipeline job (Azure Resource Group Deployment).

After deployment added additional configurations other than default configurations for Function App through portal.

For adding new resources, I have updated my 'template.json' and redeployed again. But this removes all my manual configuration of the existing Function App and set it to the default config settings in the template file. :( . Anyone please tell me a way for sort this problem.

Is there any property that helps to retain the resources and its configuration unchanged while deployment using ARM ? I used the property 
"mode":
"Incremental" .
But this didn't work for me. It removes the existing configurations that I have created manually. Please suggest a best way to deploy and manage a resource using ARM. Is there any property or 'key : value' for adding additional settings to site config other than remove the site config and recreate it as inside the template default.

Comment: You can write script to add your additional configurations, after the deployment is done.

Comment: BTW, `Incremental` mode will only create a resource if it does not already exist. Can you confirm this behaviour in your case?

Answer (score 0):

I think your only option is to set those configurations into the ARM template. ARM templates are not always incremental but are some time declarative as in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can switch to bicep, which has the ability to merge app settings. However, I don't have the details at the moment.

bicep wouldn't be a valid path to take. Except you can generate bicep from your source arm templates if they are 2019 or newer. That way the arm temples still drives the pipeline.

I wonder if terraform has the same options?